# Binance REST API - Placing a PHP Order (POST) via Query String

Tags: php, rest, curl, binance

I am struggling using Binance's REST API. I have managed to get working GET request via query string such as pinging the server, ticker information, etc. My challenge now is performing POST request via query string using cURL. I have been scraping code from various places and referring back to the API to get pieces to work but I am unsure as to why I am getting this error returned from the result:

> **{"code":-1102,"msg":"Mandatory parameter 'signature' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."}**

[image: ERROR SHOWN ON WEBPAGE]

I echo out the signature and its a load of gibberish so I would believe that the `hash_hmac` performed at the top would be working, but honestly I got pretty lucky making the GET request work. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this would be broken?

```
$apikey = "MYKEY";
$apisecret = "MYSECRET";

$timestamp = time()*1000; //get current timestamp in milliseconds
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', "TRXBTC&type=market&side=buy&quantity=100.00&recvWindow=10000000000000000&timestamp=".$timestamp, $apisecret);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.binance.com/api/v3/order/test");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "symbol=TRXBTC&type=market&side=buy&quantity=100.00&recvWindow=10000000000000000&timestamp=".$timestamp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","X-MBX-APIKEY: ".$apikey,"signature: ".$signature));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

Comment: Please ensure you follow the terms and conditions of the site before scraping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per their API docs:

> SIGNED endpoints require an additional parameter, signature, to be sent in the **query string** or **request body**.

You are sending the signature via neither of these methods and are instead sending it through the header.

Change this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "symbol=TRXBTC&type=market&side=buy&quantity=100.00&recvWindow=10000000000000000&timestamp=".$timestamp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","X-MBX-APIKEY: ".$apikey,"signature: ".$signature));
```

To this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "symbol=TRXBTC&type=market&side=buy&quantity=100.00&recvWindow=10000000000000000&timestamp=" . $timestamp . "&signature=" . $signature);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","X-MBX-APIKEY: ".$apikey));
```

Comment: {"code":-1022,"msg":"Signature for this request is not valid."} .... This is the new error I am receiving though. Am I just doing the signature complete wrong? It almost seems like I am inputting the query string twice once into the signature and then later on in the postfields. :/

Comment: OK, this is a different error than you got before so you are getting warmer. Now you just need to fix how you are creating the signature and you will be fine. I believe I have answered your original question, have I not?

Comment: For real though, check their docs and you will see that you are not creating the signature like they show in their docs example: `symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559` you seem to be missing a few keys here...

Comment: that is really bizarre. I took your suggestion and went with the default query string they provide except i kept recvWindow higher ( I am not worried about it not executing at this point just functionality) and now it works. The query string that I was using earlier is a different way to place a MARKET order instead of a LIMIT order. I hope i can go back and fix this to a market order with my original string. But thanks for your help it is truly appreciated :)

Comment: No problem, best of luck with it.

Comment: @WebCode.ie perfect answer. helped me a lot. Tnx!

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 

$secret = "F................";
$key = "D.................";

$s_time = "timestamp=".time()*1000;

$sign=hash_hmac('SHA256', $s_time, $secret);
    
$url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?".$s_time.'&signature='.$sign;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-MBX-APIKEY:'.$key));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, true);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, using [php-curl-class](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class)

```
    // Variables
    // url, key and secret is on separate file, called using require once
    $endPoint = "/api/v3/order/test";
    $coin = "BTC";
    $fiat = "EUR";
    $symbol = $coin . "" . $fiat;
    $side = "BUY";
    $type = "LIMIT";
    $timeInForce = "GTC";
    $quantity = 1;
    $price = 10000;
    $timestamp = time();

    // Constructing query arrays
    queryArray = array(
        "symbol" => $symbol,
        "side" => $side,
        "type" => $type,
        "timeInForce" => $timeInForce,
        "quantity" => $quantity,
        "price" => $price,
        "timestamp" => $timestamp*1000
    );
    $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", http_build_query($queryArray), $secret);
    $signatureArray = array("signature" => $signature);
    $curlArray = $queryArray + $signatureArray;

    // Curl : setting header and POST
    $curl->setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    $curl->setHeader("X-MBX-APIKEY",$key);

    $curl->post($url . "" . $endPoint, $curlArray);

    if ($curl->error) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $curl->errorCode . ': ' . $curl->errorMessage . "\n";
    }
    $order = $curl->response;
    print_r($order);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and nothing of above doesn't helped.
So I finaly figured out how to make order on my way.
So, maybe this helps someone.

```
function Kupovina($buy_parametri) {
$key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$s_time = "timestamp=".time()*1000;
$timestamp = time()*1000; //get current timestamp in milliseconds
$sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $buy_parametri."&timestamp=".$timestamp, $secret);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $buy_parametri."&".$s_time."&signature=".$sign);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","X-MBX-APIKEY: ".$key));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $response;
}


$buy_parametri = "symbol=BTCUSDT&type=market&side=buy&quantity=0.00086";
```

Call function:

```
Kupovina($buy_parametri);
```